# How I can remove a semicolon in Vancouver style

Tags: bibtex

I use the Vancouver style in BibTeX (`\bibliographystyle{vancouver}`). In some of my references, a semicolon (in the image it is shown in yellow) appears at the end of the reference. I want to remove that semicolon.

[image]

My MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}{myrefs.bib}
@article{perez2021offset,
author = {Anthony Perez and Yu Yang},
title = {Offset-free ARX-based adaptive model predictive control applied to a nonlinear process},
journal = {ISA Transactions},
year = {2021}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[journal, 10pt,  onecolumn]{IEEEtran}
\renewcommand\IEEEkeywordsname{Keywords}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lem}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
\title{ Fractional}
\maketitle
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\section{Introduction}
\IEEEPARstart{F}{ractional}  in \cite{perez2021offset} 
\bibliographystyle{vancouver}
\bibliography{myrefs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I want to remove the semicolon, which in the image is shown in yellow.

Comment: Please provide more information about your document setup and about the TeX distribution you employ. The reason I ask for this information is that I am unable to produce a `;` (semicolon) If I construct a minimum working example and the `vancouver.bst` file located at `/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/vancouver/vancouver.bst`. I use MacTeX2021.

Comment: I add my code. I use  IEEEtran class

Comment: @HossenHassanzadth I cannot reproduce your error when I run the MWE with: pdflatex, BibTex, pdflatex, pdflatex. Can you post more code or confirm what happens when you run the file the way I have run it please, see how it looks when I run it -> [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7j42A.png)

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor I run the way you run; it works correctly. Do you have IEEEtran class?

Comment: I do, I use TexWorks so I have almost all packages/document classes. Perhaps there is an error in your actual .bib file and it has an ; after the year, it is easy for mistakes like that to occur. So the MWE runs correctly on your system now then?

Comment: @LaccaseTVersicolor, you must put myrefs.bib  in a separate file and then write \bibliography{myrefs} at the end of the main file